# Как подставлять значения вместо реального?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть города, с автоподгрузкой

```
var states = ['Киев', 'Москва', 'Токио'
];
```

при выборе города они в `input` устанавливаются как написано выше типа Киев и т.д.
а нужно что бы устанавливалось в виде

```
 var states = ['kiev', 'moscow', 'tokio'
    ];
```

но пользователь это видеть не должен

```js
 var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Киев', 'Москва', 'Токио'
];
 
$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/css/examples.css" />
<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="ГОРОД">
</div>
```

Comment: В плане пользователь этого видеть не должен?

Comment: @Horchynskyi неправильно выразился, ну что бы Пользователь видел как **Киев** а на самом деле в инпате значение было **kiev**

Comment: думаю это нереально ведь value отвечает за то что написанно в input, только если сохранять значение kiev в другой атрибут думаю

Comment: @Horchynskyi да хотя бы в другой атрибут я уже тут задолбался искать, в документации вообще не сображаю

Answer (score 1):

В интернете нарыл такую функцию не знаю подойдет ли вам но всё же.
Просто транслитит то что введено в строку и по моему должно работать даже если виберете подсказку город, но надо затестить.
Добавляет это в атрибут data-translit и тогда уже значение с него можно брать

```js
function translit(){
// Символ, на который будут заменяться все спецсимволы
var space = '-'; 
// Берем значение из нужного поля и переводим в нижний регистр
var text = $('#city').val().toLowerCase();
     
// Массив для транслитерации
var transl = {
'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 'е': 'e', 'ё': 'e', 'ж': 'zh', 
'з': 'z', 'и': 'i', 'й': 'j', 'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n',
'о': 'o', 'п': 'p', 'р': 'r','с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'u', 'ф': 'f', 'х': 'h',
'ц': 'c', 'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'sh','ъ': space, 'ы': 'y', 'ь': space, 'э': 'e', 'ю': 'yu', 'я': 'ya',
' ': space, '_': space, '`': space, '~': space, '!': space, '@': space,
'#': space, '$': space, '%': space, '^': space, '&': space, '*': space, 
'(': space, ')': space,'-': space, '\=': space, '+': space, '[': space, 
']': space, '\\': space, '|': space, '/': space,'.': space, ',': space,
'{': space, '}': space, '\'': space, '"': space, ';': space, ':': space,
'?': space, '<': space, '>': space, '№':space
}
                
var result = '';
var curent_sim = '';
                
for(i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
    // Если символ найден в массиве то меняем его
    if(transl[text[i]] != undefined) {
         if(curent_sim != transl[text[i]] || curent_sim != space){
             result += transl[text[i]];
             curent_sim = transl[text[i]];
                                                        }                                                                             
    }
    // Если нет, то оставляем так как есть
    else {
        result += text[i];
        curent_sim = text[i];
    }                              
}          
                
result = TrimStr(result);               
                
// Выводим результат 
$('#city').data('translit', result);
console.log($('#city').data('translit'));
}
function TrimStr(s) {
    s = s.replace(/^-/, '');
    return s.replace(/-$/, '');
}
// Выполняем транслитерацию при вводе текста в поле
$(function(){
    $('#city').on('input', function(){
         translit();
         return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="city" type="text" data-translit="" placeholder="Город">
```

Comment: Бррррррррррр...

Answer (score 0):

Это ответ

```
var stocksData = [
        {
            "company_name": "Facebook",
            "code": "fb",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Google",
            "code": "goog",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Yahoo",
            "code": "yhoo",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Apple",
            "code": "aapl",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Royal Mail",
            "code": "rmg.l",
        },
     ];

var stocks = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('company_name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: stocksData
    });

    stocks.initialize();

    $('.typeahead').typeahead(
        null, {
        name: 'stocks',
        displayKey: 'company_name',
        source: stocks.ttAdapter()
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data){            
        $('#typeahead').val(data.code);        
    });
```

`

http://jsfiddle.net/7z9qA/